# keyboard hide edit text position not scroll up when typing in fragment

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

I have fragment Inside the fragment and there, at bottom I put edit text. When I am typing on edit text keyboard is getting open which is hiding form, My form view is not scrolling up to see all the textboxes.

Comment: please post your xml code

Answer (score 0):

Just put your codes in ScrollView. Check the example below

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/login_form"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/reg_no_login_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="#FFF"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="8dp">


    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_login_input"
        android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="8dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnID"
        style="?android:textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_primary"
        android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout></ScrollView>
```